# How do the font properties used influence the size of the PDF generated with IText?

Tags: pdf, fonts, itext, filesize

I am building a PDF compressor using `ITextSharp` and so far I am extracting the images, reducing them and putting them in their proper places.

This process is already giving me very positive results, however I was using an paid software and noticed that their out-coming font is slightly different from the original.

What I would like to know is if **this change from one font to another would influence the final result of the size of my generated pdf file.**

I think the most important changes would be in weight and font type, since changing the font size does not make much sense in this process.

Thank you.

Comment: *"if this change from one font to another would influence the final result of the size of my generated pdf file"* - to say anything interested, more information on *this change* are necessary. It in particular does not suffice to know that the *result is looking slightly different*, instead one needs to know what actually changed internally. If you cannot tell, please share the PDF before and after manipulation by that paid software.

Answer (score 0):

Quite possibly yes, fonts can definitely be a source of bloat in a PDF.  Depending on if the font is fully embedded or only a subset is embedded for example can influence the size due to fonts.

A good PDF compressor will attempt to reduce size to due to fonts where possible.  With that being said fonts are a very complicated animal in PDF and are very easy to get incorrect so choose your tools wisely.